# Представить обработку результата программы на Linux в .sh-скрипте

Tags: linux, bash

Необходимо сделать обработку результата выполнения App.jar файла на Linux, в .sh-скрипте. На Windows обработка выглядит следующим образом (в .bat файле):

```
java -jar App.jar
if NOT %errorlevel% == 0 goto M_NO
...
...
goto M_END
:M_NO
echo Ошибка расчета.
pause
:M_END
exit
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, представить обработку результата программы на Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

командный язык оболочки обладает довольно распространённым условным оператором:

```
if команда; then команда; else команда; fi
```

если подставить в него упомянутые вами команды, то получится:

```
if java -jar App.jar; then ...; else echo "ошибка расчета."; fi
```

Comment: И не забываем сказать, что специальная переменная с кодом ошибки выглядит так: `$?`.

Comment: @0andriy есть башизм PIPESTATUS

    Array variable holding exit status(es) of last executed foreground pipe.